# Custom Regex validation firing on all inputs

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm writing a .NET MVC application and using unobtrusive validation to sanitize my client inputs based on data annotations in my model. I have an input that I do not want to allow HTML tags into and would like to display a custom error message if an html tag is entered. As such I have created a data annotation with a custom regex expression to cover these conditions, like so:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must provide a First Name.")]
[RegularExpression(@"<[a-z][\s\S]*>", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

The issue with this is, no matter what character, whether it be `<test>` or whether it be `abc` will cause the `Invalid Character` message to appear. The required attribute works fine, and if I try a simple regex such as:

```
[RegularExpression("[a-z]", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
```

This works 100% as expected, leading me to believe my regex is incorrect, nut I know it works for HTML validation as I can prove it out with online tools. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `@"<[a-z][\s\S]*>"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried that approach but just did again, it leaves the same result. Validation fires on all values.

Also, I'm not too sure how my question is a duplicate of the linked one? Maybe I'm dumb but I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: Ok, so that means you want to only show the error if a string *contains* `<{LETTER}{anything_here}>`, right? Probably you want `@"^.*<[a-zA-Z][^>]*>.*$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah my goal is string like `<test>` or `a <test>` fail out, but input without html entities all work fine. Sadly that regex did not work either, when I input `a` into the textbox, the validation warning is triggered.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done

Comment: Try `^[^<>]*$` for a quicker regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation of the RegularExpressionAttribute, it states:

> Specifies that a data field value in ASP.NET Dynamic Data must match the specified regular expression.

So your attribute is doing the exact opposite of what you want. Try with:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!.*<.*>).*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid character")]
```

Comment: By god you're right! That did it! Not sure how I overlook that but thank you none the less!

Comment: Sometime it's hard to see the elephant in front of us, @Halter . Maybe you should take a look at the rubber duck debugging method ;)

Comment: You would think that if it _matches_ the regex, the error would be thrown, but I guess not.